# 2008 Chrysler Town and Country: RPMs change, but speed doesn't

Tags: engine, transmission, chrysler

Every so often, my 2008 Chrysler Town and Country feels like it holds back: the speed stays the same, but the RPMs go up. It makes a funny sound.

It will stop for a couple of days, but then, it happens again.

It has no diagnostic trouble codes (DTCs) for the transmission or engine. It has a big oil leak at the top of the engine.

1. What could be causing this?
2. How do I diagnose this?

Comment: I had Tranny looked at he said it was fine

Comment: Did "he" see the van while it was having this issue?

Comment: No because it only does it once in a while

Answer (score 2):

I would definitely address the oil leak first and foremost, but it sounds like your transmission is slipping.

Comment: I only have until the 12th dor warrityTranny guy said it was fine ugh I am so upset I love this

Comment: Intermittent problems are frustrating because they never happen while the mechanic is looking at the car. Try to find a pattern for when it happens. When did it start exactly?

Comment: I am just driving and it happens what speed I am going itbstays on thatbrpm go up then it goes away

Comment: Does it happen soon after you start the car? After you've been driving for a while? Uphills? Downhills? Cold morning? Warm afternoon?